# WPF display embedded resources images

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, bitmapsource

I'm trying to display an embedded PNG image, it's returned as System.Drawing.Bitmap.

```
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:GUI.Resources.Localization;assembly=GUI.Resources"

<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static res:MyGlobalResources.TestImage}}"/>
```

The only way is converting convert Bitmap to BitmapSource?